# confusions about firebase / cloud firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, serverless

I been working on a React project using firebase auth and cloud firestore as the database and I been reading the official documents. But I am grappling with the idea of whether to use mobile/web SDKs and server client libraries and I am afraid I might have some misconceptions about Cloud Firestore Security Rules.

1. I read this page https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/client/libraries several times and it is about SDKs and client libraries for firestore. It seems to me  that it suggests there are two ways of using firestore: one is through `Mobile and web SDKs` and one is through `Server client libraries`. And if I am using `Mobile and web SDKs` then my project would be classified as `serverless` since I am only building the front end and let Goole to handle the database and user authentication. The other way to use firestore, which is `Server client libraries`, it seems like it is meant to be used with your own server. It then refers to this as `client libraries` in the section, But the thing I don't quite understand is, what does **client** mean here? I'm sure it doesn't mean the same thing as in "*the mobile and web SDKs support serverless app architectures where **clients** connect directly to your Cloud Firestore database.*", where I assume a client is an end user who is browsing your website or web app. So what does this the **client** mean as in `Server client libraries`?
2. Since I am only able to build front end app or the client side app, I guess I should go with `Mobile and web SDKs` option to start using the firebase. Here comes the second question, when selecting a starting mode for my Cloud Firestore Security Rules, there are two modes: `Test mode`
   and `Locked mode`. For `Test mode`, it says "*Good for getting started with the mobile and web **client libraries**, but allows anyone to read and overwrite your data. After testing, make sure to review the Secure your data section.*". My first confusion is, does **client libraries** refer to the `Server client libraries` previously I mentioned? If so, as a serverless project without a server I cannot technically I cannot choose this mode? Then for `Locked mode` it says, "*Denies all reads and writes from mobile and web clients. Your authenticated application servers (C#, Go, Java, Node.js, PHP, Python, or Ruby) can still access your database.*" Again this option seems like it is not for me since it mentioned **Your authenticated application servers**, and for my project I don't have a server, or the server is on the google cloud platform. So can someone please correct me if I am understanding this wrong. Also, if I opt-in the `Test mode`, I suppose it allows anyone to read and overwrite my data. But I feel like there needs more explanation on the word ***anyone*** here. I think at least the person needs to have the exact firebase configuration as my project has. something like this

   ```
     const config = {
     apiKey: "myapikey",
     authDomain: "my-auth-domain.firebaseapp.com",
     databaseURL: "my-db-url.com",
     projectId: "my-pid",
     storageBucket: "my-storage-bucket",
     messagingSenderId: "my-sender-id",
   };
   ```

   to access my database. I think by **anyone**, here it means anyone with this config file and doesn't need to log in to my project in order to mess with my database. This is my understanding, can someone please correct me? Finally, in my case, I just want that anyone who can log in to my project can have access to the database(both read and write). Which mode(`test` or `locked`)  should I go with? Or I need more configuration for this?
3. Is it true that whether I choose `web SDKs` or `Server client libraries` to start my firestore project, I all need to use `firebase-admin`? But do I need to use `Firebase CLI` to `init` my project as a firebase project with the automatically generated `firebase.json`?
4. The official documents constantly use the word `web` and `node.js`, such as this image. [image]. I actually don't know what they exactly mean. If I am writing React, should I go with `web` or `node.js`? If it belongs to `web`, I am importing stuff like `import firebase from "firebase/app";` in my react project, these are also modules for `Node.js`. Again I am confused here.

I know this might be too long to read and the questions might be a bit trivial but I really appreciate if someone could clear up my confusion about firebase.

Comment: Would you consider dennisjkibo’s answer as approved. I think it’s a very detailed, nicely crafted one. He’d get StackOverflow points if you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, Here are the answers to your questions:

> 1) So what does this the client mean as in Server client libraries?

Server client libraries are used to access Firebase from servers which run on Java, Python, Go etc.

> 2) Which mode(test or locked) should I go with? Or I need more
>   configuration for this?

Test mode opens your database to the public which means any user can access your database without authenication.

Locked mode keeps your database locked down by default. You can then add rules to grant access to certain read or writes.

I would recommend to start out the project with this and later configure firestore security rules to open up access to your database according to your application's requirements. You can find references here : https://fireship.io/snippets/firestore-rules-recipes/

> 3) Is it true that whether I choose web SDKs or Server client libraries
>   to start my firestore project, I need to use firebase-admin? But do I
>   need to use Firebase CLI to init my project as a firebase project with
>   the automatically generated firebase.json?

firebase-admin available on npm is the Firebase Admin Node.js SDK to access your firebase database with admin privileges. This can be useful when you initialize/access the application specific configurations and parameters in your database.

You don't need Firebase command-line to initialize your firebase project and generate the firebase config file. You can access it through Firebase console of your project once you create your project in firebase. Reference : https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592?hl=en

> 4) If I am writing React, should I go with web or node.js?

You should go with Web because node.js SDK is used for access to your Firebase services from privileged environments (such as servers or cloud) in Node.js.

Reference: https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase

**Additional Point:** Found this for React in the Google's documentation for FIrebase SDKs. https://github.com/tylermcginnis/re-base

Hope its clearer now.